# System.Reflection.Assembly.FullName returning out of date information?

Tags: .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I replaced the EXE of a Windows service with a new version after stopping the service.  The EXE is definitely the new version, and Windows Explorer Properties shows the new version.

However, the assembly (when loaded with `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile`) reports a `.FullName` which seems to indicate that it is not the latest version.

This did not happen on the first site I deployed it to, so now my version reporting system seems to indicate that this site isn't upgraded.  (The version reporting is managed by a separate ASP.NET web service which publishes all the versions of assemblies in certain directories, it is this web service which is calling `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile`).

What's up here?  Is there some kind of caching (the web service would have last inspected that assembly yesterday before it was upgraded)?

The code is pretty basic:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo assemblies = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(DirectoryName);
foreach (var f in assemblies.GetFiles(Pattern))
{
    var a = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(f.FullName);
    l.Add(new VersionManager.Assembly(f.Name, f.LastWriteTime, a.FullName));
}
return l; // l is List<VersionManager.Assembly>
```

Deleting the EXE and replacing it (instead of just overwriting it) had no effect.

I wrote a little console application and ran it directly on the system about 3.5 hours after the last inquiry of the web service and was very surprised to find it returning the correct version.  I then queried the web service and it returned the correct version.

Nothing changed with the binary or the web service (although the web app it was part of may have been recycled, the web service itself doesn't store the information it retrieves about the assemblies, it simply sends them out in the response)

**UPDATE - 2011-12-20:**

This problem has re-occurred.  I deployed to one site, then ran my inventory program on all sites and the site reported the correct version.  I deployed to two more sites and, properties on the DLL give the correct version, but the version information reported by loading it with System.Reflection on the two additional sites is out of date.  It appears to be cached somewhere after the first call and re-used for the second call.

**Clarification**

There is an IIS ASP.NET (.NET 2.0) web service which reports the DLL versions of components in directories on the system (directories which are not part of the web service).  One of those directories contains a Windows Service's EXE and configuration.  When the Windows Service is stopped, the EXE replaced and the web service inquired, it sometimes reports the old version.  If the web service hasn't been called in a while, it appears that replacing the EXE will be reported correctly on the next inquiry.  If the web service is called before the replacement, it reports no change after the replacement, despite the fact that the EXE has been replaced and reports the correct version through Windows Explorer etc.

I noticed that the LoadFile is not accompanied by any sort of unload.  Even though the reference to the assembly goes out of scope, I wonder if it stays loaded (and thus not refreshed in a subsequent call, and thus still reporting out of date information) until IIS or whatever expires it out.  Is there a way to unload an assembly?  Is there a way to get an assembly file's version information without loading it in the first place?

Comment: do you have an ASP.NET web service checking the version of your windows service by loading it by path and checking the assembly version?

Comment: @Davide Piras - The web service gets a list of all DLL and EXE files in a particular directory, and uses `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile` to load them and gets the `.FullName.`

Comment: can you show more code? it could be that some assemblies are not updated with latest version in the place the web service is loading them from.

Comment: @Davide Piras That's about it.  The FullName is a string which is of the form "JobSchedulerWinService, Version=5.7.1.14775, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" - this just gets stored in the Assembly object in its constructor.  File is just a basic application file component.  Assembly and Report derive from it.  The web service then responds with a collection of Assemblies, Files, Reports etc. in XML.

Comment: Is this in a .net 4 runtime or a .net 2 runtime? Just to understand fully: The Assembly.LoadFile calls take place in a windows service that just got upgraded? Does the appdomain shadowcopy files? As I understand it is not reproducable? So you are not able to have a fusion log running in log all binds mode to find out what assembly is actually loaded by fusion? How are the assemblies different, version? or also by name?

Comment: Are you adding any of your assemblies into the GAC (Global Aseembly Cache)? Can you check if there's any entry in c:\windows\assembly that would refer to older version? How about any reference to the assembly inside your project?

Comment: @rene I added some clarification - .net 2, the calls are not in the windows service, no shadow copy (these files it is attempting to get versions on aren't in an IIS app), seems reproducible, but timing sensitive, since the cache seems to take a while to clear, EXE is different only by version.

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski Nothing in the GAC, nothing in the web service references that windows service assembly, it's just another component of the system, but unused by the web service or the web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(FileName) loads the assembly and there is no way to unload the assembly without unloading the AppDomain completely.

In order to inspect an assembly without loading it, the alternative is the small change from this:

```
var a = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(f.FullName);
```

to this:

```
var a = System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(f.FullName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the use of an Inspect Appdomain solve the issue as well? Or does security disallow creation of new domaion?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a new domain for loading extra Assemblies
            AppDomain inspectDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Inspect");

            // attach handler to show that no assemblies are loaded in the current domain
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad +=new AssemblyLoadEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad);

            // another prove
            int startcount = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Length;

            // now call the inspection method in the inspectionDomain
            inspectDomain.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(Inspect));

            // what is the count on assemblies in the curent domain
            int endcount = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Length;

            // show it
            Console.WriteLine("Appdomain {2} # start: {0}  and end {1}", 
                startcount, 
                endcount, 
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);

            // unload our inspectdomain and therefor the loaded assemblies
            AppDomain.Unload(inspectDomain);

            // pause so we can see
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void  CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
        {
            // write a line for a loaded assembly
            Console.WriteLine("program domain: {0}", args.LoadedAssembly.FullName);
        }

        public static void Inspect()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inspecting...");
            int startcount = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Length;
            var assemblies = new DirectoryInfo(
                    @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727");
            foreach (var f in assemblies.GetFiles("System.Data.*.dll"))
            {
                var a = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(f.FullName);
                Console.WriteLine("name:{0}, rt:{1}", a.FullName, a.ImageRuntimeVersion);
            }
            int endcount = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Length;
            Console.WriteLine("Appdomain {2} start: {0}  and end {1}", 
                startcount, 
                endcount, 
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
            Console.WriteLine("Done Inspecting...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I learned, you can either set up a throwaway AppDomain like this, or use the lighter weight AssemblyName class.